# Is there a good emacs mode for displaying and editing huge delimiter separated files?

Tags: emacs, csv, alignment

I've been searching without finding for a while for a mode that makes editing huge tab/comma/colon-separated files easy. I've been wanting a mode that ensures that columns always line up, just like org-mode tables. I know I can easily turn the whole file into an org-mode table and then turn it back when I'm done, but that gets really slow with huge files, and is a hassle for quick edits (there's also the problem of what happens if a field contains a vertical bar). So does anyone know of either a mode or a built-in function/variable I can use so that I can get a file like

```
col1\tcol2\tcol3
very long column1\tcol2\tcol3
```

displayed like

```
col1               col2  col3
very long column1  col2  col3
```

? (perhaps with some color lining the separator)

Comment: Should this be moved to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: (These days I mostly use [visidata](http://visidata.org/), cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510642/27186 , for this kind of task.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps you could tell us what you've already found and rejected?

If you've been searching, then you must surely have seen http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CsvMode ? You don't mention it, or say why it wasn't any good, though.

SES (Simple Emacs Spreadsheet) might be a useful approach:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(ses)` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can create a `ses-mode` buffer and yank tab-delimited data into it (that's the import mechanism).

It's probably more hassle than you were after, though, and I'm not sure how well it will perform with "huge" files.

Comment: Note also that `csv-mode` is now in GNU ELPA (and that is not mentioned in the emacswiki because I happen to use an IP that's banned).

Comment: Wow. How could I have missed that … (I was searching for table editing modes and tabs and such, never thought of searching for just csv.) Thanks!

Comment: csv-mode not compiling for me on 24.2.1 on osx.

Comment: @tenpn: I've just compiled it with M-x byte-compile-file on osx in 24.2.1. What errors do you get in *Compile-Log* buffer?

Comment: check it out here: https://gist.github.com/860fd8e19f8a0d69193f running 24.2.1 installed view brew install emacs --cocoa.

Comment: ..installing csv-mode 1.5.

Comment: A problem I have with CSV-mode is that when navigating long rows, if I scroll down too fast while viewing a column toward the end (after scrolling right) the viewport jumps back to the beginning of each row, so I can't watch the values while scrolling continuously.  I don't suppose anyone has found a workaround for this?

Comment: @DarrenRinger Maybe setting a goal column would help?  `C-x C-n` to set and `C-u C-x C-n` to clear.

Answer (score 13):

Try `csv-mode`, which works in at least Emacs 24.

You can set the variable `csv-separators` to change the separator if you do not use the default one (comma).

See [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CsvMode).

Comment: To change or define new separators you can add next line to your .emacs file: (setq csv-separators '("," ";" "|" " "))

Comment: I ended up using csv-mode, but aligning the whole file was too slow, so instead I use this keybinding that align just visible lines: `(add-hook
 'csv-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (define-key csv-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c")
     (defun csv-align-visible (&optional arg)
       "Align visible fields"
       (interactive "P")
       (csv-align-fields nil (window-start) (window-end))))))` (ideally it would align on scrolling, but I couldn't get that to work very well)

Comment: Has anybody tried changing the separator? Regardless of which sign(s) I try it ends up using comma only. (emacs 25.2 / cvs-mode 1.50)

Comment: @Markus: You need to **customize** the variable, and reapply the mode or reload the file.

Comment: @choroba: Yes, I did that. `M-x describe-variable RET csv-separators` reports "Its value is (";")". But strangely csv-separator-chars is still set to 44 (the ascii code for comma). I put this into my ~/.emacs and restarted emacs, so I don't think it's a reloading issue.

Comment: Works for me in 24.5.1.

Answer (score 5):

As @choroba mentioned, use `csv-mode`. To answer your question specifically:

- Make sure your separator is in `csv-separators`, which for example you can set with

  ```lisp
  (setq csv-separators '("," "    "))
  ```
- Use `csv-align-fields` (default keybinding `C-c C-a`) to line up the field values into columns.

@unhammer's comment about aligning only visible lines is great. Their code properly indented:

```lisp
(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key csv-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-M-a")
              (defun csv-align-visible (&optional arg)
                "Align visible fields"
                (interactive "P")
                (csv-align-fields nil (window-start) (window-end))
                )
              )
            )
          )
```

Comment: Is it possible to align "selection" instead of visible?

Comment: @SFbay007: you can use `(csv-align-fields nil (window-start) (window-end)` instead in the code above. "Region" is the emacs term for selection.

Comment: A small comment on "properly indented", it's very unlispy to leave hanging closing parentheses. Proper Lisp style calls for having all of them bunched together on the last non-whitespace line, so `(csv-align-fields nil (window-start) (window-end))))))`

Answer (score 3):

There is pretty-column.el, which I found in Group gnu.emacs.sources years ago (it was added in 1999).  That group is now blocked, by Google.  I just used pretty-column.el on a ~5000 line tab-separated text file that Org mode choked on (Org mode has a 999 line limit on converting such a file--for that reason).
Added in edit: This seems to now be called delim-col.el (see [this Emacs Wiki entry](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DelimColPackage)); the author is the same person.

Comment: wow, built-in to emacs, and useful for adding delimiters to rectangles and such too, thanks for the tip!

Comment: This is a great command to format a file. Important to emphasize: it modifies the file to format it. So it is not just a display aid.