# Edit csv tables in emacs 24

Tags: csv, org-mode, emacs24

How can I edit csv tables with the comfort I can edit tables in org mode?

I tried `csv-mode`, but its code is unmaintained since August 2004 and the code says

> This package is intended for use with GNU Emacs 21 (only).

Which package will support editing csv files in Emacs 24 best?

One solution could be to use `org-mode`, but I could not set the column seperator to `,` yet.
If `org-mode` is running I could convert the table to the `|` separated layout with `C-c |`. But I think it should be possible to make it easier. Something like this (not working example):

```
tea,       price
fruit,     3.45
earl grey, 2.42
ginger,    1.63
# eval: (setq 'org-mode-separator ",")
# eval: (org-mode)
# End:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10617655/1575066

Comment: @Dualinity I started SES (Simple Emacs Spreadsheet) with M-x ses-mode, read the very short introduction and played around with it. But ses-mode has nearly no functionality. At least it should render the data like a real spreadsheet with aligned columns. Similar to the orgmode http://orgmode.org/img/table2.jpg But there is no need for | signs. proper alignment on , would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Work on csv-mode has been restarted. See https://sites.google.com/site/fjwcentaur/emacs. You can install the latest version from elpa with `M-x package-install csv-mode`. It works perfectly with emacs 24.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit quick & dirty, but might work for you: You can temporarily replace all commas with pipes (using <kbd>M-%</kbd>) and then turn on the [org-table minor mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Orgtbl-mode.html) with:

<kbd>M-x orgtbl-mode</kbd>

When you're done, you replace all pipes with commas again. Just make sure that there aren't any pipe characters or quotes commas in your cell fields before you begin.

Comment: Changing the separator can more reliably be achieved using csvtool (apt-get install csvtool): csvtool -u '|' cat file.csv